Difficulty Displaying Full Label for Actions Column in LWC lightning-tree-grid Component
I would like to try to display the entire label of the actions column for the LWC lightning-tree-grid component.
Here there is a screen of the issue
Do you happen to have any suggestions?
Thank you very much!
I am having quite a bit of difficulty using methods recommended in the documentation, such as the initialWidth attribute: 300.
